# How to set an alias in nixos?

Tags: alias, nixos

In ubuntu I had a `~/.bashrc` file with a number of aliases of the form

```
alias gs='git status'
```

How do I set an alias in nixos?

Comment: You still can use `.bashrc`, see this related [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377663/23003)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
environment.interactiveShellInit = ''
  alias gs='git status'
'';
```

More: https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/options.html#opt-environment.interactiveShellInit

Answer (score 11):

You can set [`programs.bash.shellAliases`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#programs.bash.shellAliases) in your global configuration:

```
programs.bash.shellAliases = {
  l = "ls -alh";
  ll = "ls -l";
  ls = "ls --color=tty";
};
```

In general, one can search for configuration options at [this nixos.org page](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html)